# PHP + SQL - Trying to retrieve IDs from multiple users. (Comma Seperation)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, code-snippets

I am working on wordpress and trying to write a code snippet that will convert "Alternative Contacts" that people have typed for their profiles into profile links for better navigation.

Here is code of where I have managed to get to:

```
add_shortcode( 'Alternative_Contact_Links', function () {
global $current_user;
global $current_user_manager;
global $wpdb;
global $details;

$contacts = '';
$contactsnames = '';
$dummyurl = "https://altranet-test/user/";
$displaycontacts = '';

$urldata = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH );
$urldata = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $urldata);

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user_manager =get_metadata( 'user', $urldata, 'user_id', true );

$sqlquery = "SELECT DISTINCT wp_usermeta.meta_value, wp_usermeta.user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'Alternative_Contact' AND wp_usermeta.user_id = '$urldata'";

$usernames = array();
$nameArray = array();
$usernames = $wpdb->get_results($sqlquery);

foreach ($usernames as $details) {
$names = $details->meta_value;
echo $names;
}   
)};
```

This is working as expected and $names is returning "Joe Bloggs, John Smith" as one string.
This is where I become confused. In order to create hyperlinks to each of the users profiles, I need to get the IDs of each of these names. However, how do I pass both names into an SQL statement.

For example:

```
$sqlquery2 = "SELECT wp_users.ID FROM wp_users WHERE wp_users.display_name = '$names'";

$result2 = $wpdb->get_results($sqlquery2);
     foreach ($result2 as $details2) {
         $managerid = $details2->ID;

$profilelinks = '<a href="'.$teammembers.'">'.$names.'</a>';
$displayallteammembers .= $profilelinks. "<Br>";
 }
    return "<strong>Manager's (above) Direct Reports</strong>"."<Br>".$displayallteammembers;
 });
```

This is from an example I've previously used but doesnt work as I cant retrieve both IDs from the database?

Anyone know how I can comma seperate the $names string and run each name through the SQL statement and make them links?

Thanks!

EDIT (using IN to try and retrieve both IDs attempt):

```
SELECT wp_users.ID FROM wp_users WHERE wp_users.display_name IN ('Joe Bloggs' , 'John Smith').
```

(This way the result is Joe Bloggs ID because it retrieves it then stops.

Comment: You could try a few things, like an SQL in statement, WHERE users.display_name IN ('John Doe', 'Jane Doe')

Comment: @ZacharyCraig that was my thought, although the IN statement only returned 1 ID or value not both or all in the array :(

Comment: Well, how are you building the in statement? my guess is you either had a group by, or your in statement was malformed.

Comment: I will edit the post above with the statement i tried

Comment: added the statement @ZacharyCraig

Comment: are you getting comma seperated names for $names = $details->meta_value in each loop run ?

Comment: @MohammedShafeek yes i think so, because in the database it is only stored in one cell. the result of the echo inside the loop is "Joe Bloggs, John Smith".